# Access 2007 - two read-only tables, several end users - design query

Tags: ms-access-2007

I've inherited an Access 2007 database with a remit to make it available to our sales reps (10 of them) who work on laptops, which can connect to a central server but they also have a requirement to use the db offline when they are on their travels. I'm not sure how to manage this.

The db is fairly straightforward: 3 tables for customers, prices and products.
Each rep needs to have his own individual customer table, but the prices and products tables are read-only so that they are updated centrally by one person. They are updated maybe half-a dozen times a year.

I though that the simplest way would be to create a copy of the database with all three tables on a central server for each of them, then tell them to download the new copy to their laptops whenever there are any updates.

Is there any way I could automate the process (such as giving them a button on a form to press with some vba coding behind the scenes to do the copy?)

Or is there better way of managing this?

Thanks

Comment: The search phrase you're looking for is *briefcase model*. Access supports DB replication that will help. Start with [this article](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/an-introduction-to-access-2000-database-replication/), which should give you an idea of the concepts and a start.